# Wait connection method to execute then move to next line Retrofit Callback

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to get the Connection result to handle it using Retrofit API ,
here is my Code:

```
  public boolean connect() {
    this.callback.enqueue(new Callback<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<T> call, @NonNull 
         Response<T> response) {
            assert response.body() != null;
            setConnectionValid(true);
            try {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body());
                setResponse(response);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(Constants.TAG, "onResponse: " + 
        e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<T> call, @NonNull 
       Throwable t) {
            setThrowable(t);
            Log.i(Constants.TAG, "onError: " + 
        t.getLocalizedMessage());
            setConnectionValid(false);
        }
    });
    return isConnectionValid();
}
```

and execute method connect in Controller

```
  private void loginValidate()  {
    boolean isConnected;
    RetroConnection retroConnection;
    IRetrofit api = RetroSingleton.getRetroSingleton(context).create(IRetrofit.class);
    Call<User> call = api.login(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString(), "token");
    retroConnection = new RetroConnection<>(call);
    isConnected= retroConnection.connect();
    Log.i(TAG, "loginValidate: "+isConnected); //return false 
    if (isConnected) {
        ToastMessage.message(context, ConstantMessages.LOGIN_SUCCESS);
    } else {
        ToastMessage.message(context, ConstantMessages.LOGIN_FAILED);
    }
}
```

but the response takes while and "isConnected" always return false .
The point is need a way to wait the connection to be done then handle it 
without Using Threads.sleep(some time);

Comment: FYI Retrofit's [enqueue()](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#enqueue-retrofit2.Callback-) method is Asynchronous and [execute()](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#execute--) method is Synchronous. So, you need to use `execute()` method instead of `enqueue()` method to handle this kind of situation. Check this [tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests) for better understanding about this concept/method in Retrofit.

Comment: Not exactly clear what you are doing. If `loginValidate` runs on the main thread, it would be a bad idea to wait. Instead handle any UI updates in the callback methods.

Comment: @Shashanth,@Henry  still , the problem here is: 
 "isConnected= retroConnection.connect();"  return false , one sec after its become true because the connect method finish execute ... 
if i used execute() method i have to create thread in every connection that i have and do it in instant service (IntentService) . 
what I'm looking for is something like stop executing this line  isConnected= retroConnection.connect(); till the connection finish execute.